# How to install a localized MsiPackage with Burn Bootstrap Application

Tags: wix, burn

I have a number of localized MSI packages. Let's say what is localized is a start menu entry, using !(loc.StartAppDescription) .

It seems reasonable that this is done using WiX in the MSI. So I've done that, and I've generated a number of transforms based on a baseline en-US version, and I've embedded this into a final MSI, MyCoolApp-1.2.123.0.msi .

The transform can be used with a MsiProperty element with Name="TRANSFORM" Value=":it-IT" in the MsiPackage.

Each localized MSI has an auto-generated ProductCode, as is recommended, so the transform will cause a change here too along with the actual texts.

Then, I've built a Burn Bootstrapper using the Standard Bootstrapper Application which based on an InstallCondition will select a x86 or x64 version of the installers. This bootstrapper is also localized.

The bootstrapper localization works fine.
The MSI package localization works fine.

But, how do I bring them together?

There seems to be no way to actually use a localized MSI in a Burn chain. This hardly even makes sense. Why spend so much time and effort on making Windows Installers possible to localize, and also making the UI for the installation process localizable via Burn and the Standard Bootstrap Application and then not being able to use one from the other?

What am I missing? Via the wix mailing list, I've gotten an authoritative response essentially stating that "localization via MsiPackage transforms is not supported by Burn, and is non-trivial to implement" (not a literal quote, my interpretation). Still no suggestion or hint on how to actually achieve what I'm after: To install one of several possible localized MSIs based on the user culture with Burn.

I've tried doing essentially what is described here: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/My-experiences-making-a-multi-language-bundle-td7208949.html which is using InstallConditions to determine just what transform in a long chain of transform to use for the installation. This does not work, because upgrade and uninstall scenarios break in various ways.

Also, since I already have literally millions of users who have installed a non-localized MSI (what in the new scenario is the en-US baseline), I need to be able to upgrade these existing users, so all the localized MSIs need to have the same Upgrade Code as the existing MSI that is already installed in many systems.

Yes, I also did try the above method without actually using transforms, but the full localized MSI packages. Still no joy of setup, just a much larger installer.

Is there actually no-one out there who has the need to run a localized MSI Package from a Burn Bootstrapper, and has succeeded in creating such a thing?

It seems like it would be the on the Burn 101-curriculum: How to make an Burn bootstrapper to install a localized MsiPackage?

Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 1):

Is it a requirement that your different-language products can be installed SxS?

If not, drop the change of ProductCode in your transforms. One of the problems you will have with burn is that it depends on the non-transformed MSIs values of ProductCode and UpgradeCode being exactly the same when the packages are installed.

In Burn you will need your own custom code running to setup the burn/bundle variable that you will use to set the TRANSFORMS msi property you will pass to the package (along with any others that also relate to language you find you must pass in). That probably means creating your own custom BA (I haven't ever gotten BA functions to work so I don't know if that would work, although that would seem to be a perfect solution for this).

Comment: Thanks! No, SxS is not a requirement.

Can you elaborate on the statement "[burn] depends on the non-transformed MSIs values of ProductCode and UpgradeCode being exactly the same when the packages are installed"?

Do you mean to say that Burn examines the non-transformed MSI, makes it decisions based on that, and that the transformed MSI must then have the same ProductCode (and UpgradeCode) after the transform?

Comment: Also, if the ProductCode issue works out, indeed the next problem is assuring that the parameter passed to the TRANSFORMS property is a valid transform based on the users culture/language. There's both UserLanguageID  and WixStdBALanguageId ready to use, but I still need some function to implement a fallback, otherwise it might not reference a valid transform.

If I understand it correctly, it is possible to pass a variable into a MsiProperty attribute with for example Value=":[WixStdBALanguageId]"?

Comment: When the bundle is built, the MSI is read to retrieve the codes which are stored in the bundle's internal metadata. There is currently no support to extract/apply any transform during that operation. That information is used during the detection phase of operation (to know if the package is installed or not or would be upgrading or even downgrading a package already installed).

Comment: If your bundle implements the very same set of languages as your package does, the language your bundle ends up showing the user should work for you. Otherwise, yes, you will need to keep track of whatever languages you implemented for each of your packages and determine the fallbacks yourself. Automatic language detection (including fallbacks) is much improved in WiX versions 4.0 and 3.11 over previous versions.

Comment: Ok, great. It might actually work. But why so hard!? So, I'll ensure same ProductCode and UpgradeCode for all localized + baseline. New when version changes.

Comment: Name transform after LCID of supported languages in the bundle, and support the same set.
Use <MsiProperty Name="TRANSFORMS" Value=":[WixStdBALanguageId] />.
No need for Custom BA or BA functions, right?
Thanks a million for straightening this out, just hoping there're no new gotchas... There always seem to be with MSI/WiX/Bundle, but this could actually work!